# How to delete all the files associated with the users when I delete the user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make an web application in Django.Here I have created different fields in user model including profile picture and other pictures.When I delete a user,the files associated with the user doesn't get deleted.I want to delete the files,profile picture and other pictures when I delete the user.

I am using django2.2 and I have customized my own user model and admin panel.
In my user model I have added 'Profile Picture' field and 'CV' field. When I add a user in my model the profile picture are stored in 'Media/"%username/"'
directory.I want to delete the files associated with the user when I delete the user.So I have written 'on_delete=..' in the () of username but it gives an error.So is there any possible way to do it?

```py
import ..
import os
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   return os.path.join('media', instance.username, filename)
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, on_delete = 
                                         os.remove(str(user_directory_path)))
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(default='media/download(1).png', 
                                       upload_to = user_directory_path)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to = user_directory_path)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    moderator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
```

I wanted to delete the files this way

```py
username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, on_delete = 
                                         os.remove(str(user_directory_path)))
```

I have also tried this

```py
username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, pre_delete=os.rmdir(user_directory_path))
```

but these errors come
`TypeError: rmdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not function`

Comment: Not by using `on_delete`, which can only take one of a fixed number of values, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Override the `delete` method of your `User` model or add a signal handler ([`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-delete)).

Comment: Should  I write this `username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, delete = os.remove(str(user_directory_path)))`

Comment: No, I said "override the `delete()` method", as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). That doc also says it's better to use the `pre_delete` signal, so I would do that (link to how to write signal handlers in my comment above). General docs on signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/)